# How to export a build log from Xcode 13 or 14 to custom support?

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode13, xcode14

You can always:

- navigate to `"Show the Report navigator"` tab.
  `"Local"/"By Group"`
- select the proper log
- and `Copy/Paste` it

The question:
Is there the possibility to send log as a `file` to custom support?
Like: Show in Finder or smth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your build log and click `Export...`, like on screenshot below:[image]
Screenshot is taken under `Xcode 13.4.1`

Answer (score 0):

If u want to get a log file of your build, you can get it from `DerivedData -> YourProjectName -> Logs -> Build -> LogStoreManifest.plist & SomeID.xcactivitylog`.
You can copy last 2 files and paste them in any Xcode's derived data on any device and see result of these build in Xcode.